# Creating dynamically allocated arrays using Xcode's g++

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, dynamic-arrays

So, I recently tried doing this:

```
void Foo(int **bar, int size) {
    bar = new int *[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        bar[i] = new int[4];
    // Do other stuff
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int ** data;
    int size = atoi(argv[1]);
    Foo(data, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            cout << "i = " << i << ", j = " << j << ", data = " << data[i][j] << endl;
        // Do other stuff
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        delete[] data[i];
    delete[] data;
    return 0;
}
```

and invariably I would get a segfault right at that `cout` statement. After changing the code so that the array was dynamically allocated in `main` the problem went away. So, the difference between a segfault is whether or not an array is dynamically allocated and destroyed in the same function. This seems wrong to me as this shouldn't be a problem with traditional C++. I am using a MacBook with Xcode for the g++ command. Can anyone else confirm that Xcode's implementation does this?

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behavior due to pointer mismanagement.  There is nothing wrong with your C++ compiler or installation.

Comment: If you had inspected the value of `data` after the call to `Foo`, you should have seen that `data` didn't change at all.  That's what all the answers given to you will explain.  Also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487495/c-pointers-and-pointer-to-a-reference/27487983#27487983

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did inspect `data` after I called `Foo` and I did notice that it hadn't changed. However, I was under the impression that sending any pointer to a function was a pass-by-reference. And the answer given below does explain my problem, thank you

Comment: A better example is if you set data to NULL before you called `Foo`.  You would have seen that `data` would still be NULL, thus your `cout` would be working with a NULL pointer (undefined behavior).   And no, sending a pointer is pass-by-value, no different than any other value type being passed.  Pass-by-reference in C++ means *exactly* that -- passing a reference.  A pointer is not a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nothing specific to Xcode or g++ - just a bug in your code - you need to pass `bar` by reference in order to use it as an output parameter.

Change:

```
void Foo(int **bar, int size)
```

to:

```
void Foo(int ** &bar, int size)
```

Note that in general it's preferable to use e.g. `std::vector` rather than naked C-style pointers for arrays etc.

Comment: I honestly didn't know you could do that

Answer (score 0):

You pass data to Foo by value, so data in main () remains uninitialized when you allocate memory inside Foo.